# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - when iterating a dict

Tags: python, windows, list, dictionary, pywin32

I am trying to get the list of local user my windows have.

I figured it out i can get the list in a form of a dictionary using win32net.NetUserEnum, however, since i just need the username, i'm trying to fetch that information from the dict and i've managed to do it already.

But i still have a problem, the script it's returning this message:

> Administrator Traceback (most recent call last): Guest   File
>   "D:/QUIZ/OCRLAB/orissupportaut.py", line 9, in  DefaultAccount
>       for user in listausers[i]: userjohn TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable teste UtilityAccount

Anyway knows why this is happening?

Thanks

```
import win32api
import win32net
import win32netcon

listausers = win32net.NetUserEnum(None,2)

utilizadores= []
for i in range(len(listausers)):
    for user in listausers[i]:
        if type(user) == int:
            pass
        else:
            print(user.get("name"))
```

Comment: There is a reflex that you need to take. The traceback says `for user in listausers[i]` is a faulty line, so print `listausers` right before and you'll see what is wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

Does this meet your requirements? Using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of checking value of type. You're getting this error because NetUserEnum returns a list consisting of the users dict, and a few extra values (ints) as described [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32net__NetUserEnum_meth.html).

```
import win32api
import win32net
import win32netcon

listausers = win32net.NetUserEnum(None,2)

utilizadores= []
for i, users in enumerate(listausers):
    if not isinstance(users, int):
        for user in users:
            if isinstance(user, int):
                pass
            else:
                print(user.get("name"))
```

You could also just look at the dictionary itself by slicing the list.

```
for user in listausers[0]:
    print(user.get("name"))
```

Comment: I would advise to use `listausers, _, _ = win32net.NetUserEnum(None,2)` then, and remove the type check.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! That helped me a lot! I was over complicating this.

listausers  = win32net.NetUserEnum(None,2)

utilizadores= []

for user in listausers[0]:
    print(user.get("name"))
    utilizadores.append(user.get("name"))

Comment: @JoaoRossas You can also write a list comprehension: `utilizadores = [user.get("name") for user in listausers[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on CDJB's answer, I would compact everything to simply:

```
import win32api
import win32net
import win32netcon

listausers = win32net.NetUserEnum(None, 2)[0] # 0 to ignore the extra returned values.   
utilizadores = [user.get("name") for user in listausers]
```